# Optimizing a recipe/ ingredient selection algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, optimization, time-complexity

I'm working on an algorithm that will select a subset of ingredients in order to maximize the number of recipes that can be made.

For example, let's say I have a cookbook of **100 recipes** and there are **25 distinct ingredients** in the whole book. I want to know which **10 ingredients** to buy to *optimize* the number of recipes I could make.

For the sake of simplification ignore quantity and cost of ingredients.

I know I could brute-force a solution, but I'm thinking that that won't be efficient enough for the actual application.

To be clear, this is definitely not a homework problem. I've been searching for an algorithm to reduce the time complexity.

Here's what I've tried for a brute force solution:

```cs
int maxCount = 0;
int[] highCombo;
var ingredients = InitializeIngredientCombo();
do
{
   int count = 0;
   foreach(var recipe in recipes)
   {
      if(CanMake(recipe,ingredients))
      {
         count++;
      }

      if(count > maxCount)
      {
         highCombo = ingredients;
         maxCount = count;
      }
   }
}
while(IsNotLastCombo(ingredients));
```

While this solution will work, it will not work for the size of numbers I'm working on.

For example, picking 10 ingredients from a set of 800 results in over *1E22* possible options, and comparing that against a dataset of 5k recipes is... slow. This brute force solution will be running until the heat death of the universe.

Comment: This is a neat little problem that feels very much like homework. Normally with SO, we need to see what you've tried, and then we can help you from there. Especially so with a homework problem. Bang your head against it a bit, see what you come up with, and we'll see if we can assist from there. Good luck, and welcome!

Comment: @MarcL. Any ideas? Definitely not a homework problem if I'm still coming back to it. Go check out [Mixirs](https://mixirs.com) if you curious about the application.